# Error running `ng lint` in lerna monorepo for Angular package

Tags: angular, eslint, prettier, monorepo, lerna

Have a monorepo of component library packages for Angular, React, Svelte, and Vue.

I am trying to setup the Angular 16 package in packages/angular to use eslint and prettier.

When I run `ng lint` from packages/angular, I get this error that suggests it's looking in the monorepo root for the angular.json rather than the current working directory (angular.json is there)...

```
[error] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/foo/dev/carbon-charts/angular.json'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:601:3)
    at readFileSync (node:fs:469:35)
    at readJsonFile (/Users/foo/dev/carbon-charts/packages/angular/node_modules/nx/src/utils/fileutils.js:18:43)
    at readAngularJson (/Users/foo/dev/carbon-charts/packages/angular/node_modules/nx/src/adapter/angular-json.js:40:53)
    at mergeAngularJsonAndGlobProjects (/Users/foo/dev/carbon-charts/packages/angular/node_modules/nx/src/adapter/angular-json.js:44:17)
    at Workspaces.readProjectsConfigurations (/Users/foo/dev/carbon-charts/packages/angular/node_modules/nx/src/config/workspaces.js:66:98)
    at builderFunction (/Users/foo/dev/carbon-charts/packages/angular/node_modules/@nx/devkit/src/utils/convert-nx-executor.js:17:51)
    at onInput (/Users/foo/dev/carbon-charts/packages/angular/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/src/create-builder.js:139:30)
    at Object.next (/Users/foo/dev/carbon-charts/packages/angular/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/src/create-builder.js:57:25)
    at ConsumerObserver.next (/Users/foo/dev/carbon-charts/packages/angular/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Subscriber.js:113:33)
```

What makes me suspicious is the reference to `nx` above - `lerna` is based on `nx`.

These are the steps I took to add `eslint` and `prettier` to the Angular component library package...

```bash
cd packages/angular
ng add @angular-eslint/schematics
yarn add -D prettier prettier-eslint eslint-config-prettier eslint-plugin-prettier
```

The package.json in packages/angular has these relevant scripts...

```json
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "lint": "ng lint --ignore-path ../../.eslintignore",
    "format": "prettier --write src/ --ignore-path ../../.eslintignore",
  }
```

The root of my monorepo has this .eslintignore...

```
# Root-level only
.git
.yarn
pages
yarn.lock

# All packages
**/.angular
**/.DS_Store
**/.svelte-kit
**/dist
**/demo/bundle
**/node_modules
```

The packages/angular .eslintrc.json looks like this...

```json
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "!**/*"
  ],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "*.ts"
      ],
      "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended",
        "plugin:storybook/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "attribute",
            "prefix": "lib",
            "style": "camelCase"
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "element",
            "prefix": "lib",
            "style": "kebab-case"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "files": [
        "*.html"
      ],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/accessibility",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

This is packages/angular/angular.json...

```json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "./",
  "projects": {
    "charts-angular": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": ".",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "ibm",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:ng-packagr",
          "options": {
            "project": "ng-package.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "tsConfig": "tsconfig.lib.prod.json"
            },
            "development": {
              "tsConfig": "tsconfig.lib.json"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ]
          }
        },
        "storybook": {
          "builder": "@storybook/angular:start-storybook",
          "options": {
            "configDir": ".storybook",
            "tsConfig": ".storybook/tsconfig.json",
            "browserTarget": "charts-angular:build",
            "compodoc": false,
            "compodocArgs": [
              "-e",
              "json",
              "-d",
              "./"
            ],
            "port": 9006,
            "quiet": true
          }
        },
        "build-storybook": {
          "builder": "@storybook/angular:build-storybook",
          "options": {
            "configDir": ".storybook",
            "tsConfig": ".storybook/tsconfig.json",
            "browserTarget": "charts-angular:build",
            "compodoc": false,
            "compodocArgs": [
              "-e",
              "json",
              "-d",
              "./"
            ],
            "outputDir": "demo/bundle",
            "quiet": true
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "./**/*.ts",
              "./**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false,
    "packageManager": "yarn",
    "schematicCollections": [
      "@angular-eslint/schematics"
    ]
  }
}
```

Have I missed something obvious? Was able to setup eslint and prettier for all the other packages except for Angular. Should I just bypass `ng lint` and make the lint script in my package.json like the others...

```json
"lint": "prettier --plugin-search-dir . --check . --ignore-path ../../.eslintignore && eslint . --ignore-path ../../.eslintignore",
```